# I would like to use the Raspberry Pi 3 b model to configure Bluetooth mesh network and 6Lowpan for mqtt communication

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, bluetooth-mesh

1. I want to configure a mesh network with Bluetooth module that is mounted on pi3.
2. After configuring mesh network, I want to use 6LoWPAN to communicate with mqtt.

I've looked at the site. "https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/wiki/How-to-install-6LoWPAN-Linux-Kernel-on-Raspberry-Pi#802154-monitoring-example"

But I would like to use only the Bluetooth of the Raspberry pi3 to form a mesh network and a 6LoWPAN.